# VBA Excel Loop through Specific Tables to Format

Tags: vba, excel

I have 77 tables on the worksheet and I want to format only specific tables.

When performing a loop with specific named tables how do I need to format the loop?

For Example I want to change the second column in Table2, Table4, Table5 and Table6 (Shortened List for this example).

So far I have:

```
For  Table2, Table4, Table 5 In ws.ListObjects
```

On Error Resume Next

```
ws.ListObjects("Table").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Style = "Comma"
ws.ListObjects("Table").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

Next

On Error GoTo 0
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()
Dim AllTableNames As String
Dim TableNames As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
AllTableNames = "Table2,Table4,Table5,Table6"
TableNames = Split(AllTableNames, ",")

For i = LBound(TableNames) To UBound(TableNames)
    ws.ListObjects(TableNames(i)).ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Style = "Comma"
    ws.ListObjects(TableNames(i)).ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the help.